# Trigger to create a contact from a lead

Tags: trigger

I'm new to coding but have been an admin of salesforce for a few years so hopefully this is something that is simple to sort. 
I'm trying to create a trigger that creates a contact when a lead is created and when a lead field called `Paymentinfo__c` has the value `"createcontact"`. I've created the code below but it isn't creating the contact. Is is possible to create a contact in this way or is my code wrong?

```
trigger rttest on Lead (after insert) {
    for(Lead u : Trigger.new)
    {
        if ('createcontact'.equals(u.Paymentinfo__c))
        {
            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.owner=u.owner;
            c.firstname=u.firstname;
            c.lastname=u.lastname;
            c.Product_for_Activation__c='NO PRODUCT';
            c.Contact_Status__c='Non-User';
            insert c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the code is correct apart from the fact that DML is in the `for` loop which will give errors. For now please check if the trigger is active  and it will be helpful if you can post the debug log. Do you get any errors when you create a lead?

Comment: also `.equals()` is case-sensitive so if there is a 'Createcontact' value that won't work while `==` is case-insensitive.

Comment: Just use `Process Builder`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use code to accomplish this objective. Instead use `Process Builder` to create a flow.

1. Navigate to `Create` > `Workflows & Approvals` > `Process Builder`.
2. Click <kbd>New</kbd>.
   Fill in `Process Name` > `Create Contact`.
   No need to fill in `API Name`, it will auto-populate.
   You may fill in an optional `Description`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
3. Click <kbd>+ Add Object</kbd>.
   Select `Lead`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
4. Click <kbd>+ Add Criteria</kbd>.
   Fill in `Criteria Name` > `Insert`.
   Select `Formula Evaluates to True`.
   Fill in `AND(ISNEW(), [Lead].PaymentInfo__c ="createcontact")`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
5. Click <kbd>+ Add Action</kbd>.
   Select `Action Type` > `Create a Record`.
   Fill in `Action Name` > `Create Contact`.
   Select `Record Type` > `Contact`.
   Select `Field` > `Last Name`.
   Select `Type` > `Reference`.
   Select `Value` > `[Lead].LastName`.
   Add other fields as above.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
6. Click <kbd>Activate</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks very much Adrian! That's worked a treat. Thanks again for taking the time to time to answer this with great instructions

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code and check it. Also enable debug log and check if there is any exception throwing while inserting contacts and add appropriate exception handler if necessary.

```
trigger rttest on Lead (after insert) {

List<contact> conInsertList = new List<contact>();
for(Lead u : Trigger.new)
 {

    if (u.Paymentinfo__c == 'createcontact')
        {

            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.owner=u.owner;
            c.firstname=u.firstname;
            c.lastname=u.lastname;
            c.Product_for_Activation__c='NO PRODUCT';
            c.Contact_Status__c='Non-User';
            conInsertList.add(c);
    }

 }

if(conInsertList.size()>0)
         Insert conInsertList;

}
```